# FIO Benchmark Tester: Error when building from source

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiling, make, benchmark

I encountered some errors when I was trying to build the FIO from source with the 'make' command. It seems I may be missing something. Does anyone what it is?

> ```
> root@DSI:/home/main/fio-2.2.10# make
>    CC lib/libmtd_legacy.o
> In file included from lib/libmtd_legacy.c:38:0:
> lib/libmtd.h:288:8: error: unknown type name ‘uint8_t’
>         uint8_t mode);
>         ^
> lib/libmtd.h:305:4: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
>     uint64_t start, uint64_t length, void *data);
>     ^
> lib/libmtd.h:305:20: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
>     uint64_t start, uint64_t length, void *data);
>                     ^
> lib/libmtd.h:322:5: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
>      uint64_t start, uint64_t length, void *data);
>      ^
> lib/libmtd.h:322:21: error: unknown type name ‘uint64_t’
>      uint64_t start, uint64_t length, void *data);
>                        ^
> Makefile:287: recipe for target 'lib/libmtd_legacy.o' failed
> make: *** [lib/libmtd_legacy.o] Error 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

That version of fio (2.2.10) is old. Upstream fio is up to 2.21 (http://git.kernel.dk/?p=fio.git;a=tags ) at the time of writing so there's a chance you won't see this issue with a newer version...